# Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error:

> "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

From this code:

```
// Create a string of text that is used by search capabilites
var searchText = (capital.text + " " + nameEnglish.text + " " + nameLocal.text + " " + currencyCode.text).lowercaseString
updateObject["searchText"] = searchText
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is your question? The compiler tells you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I took your question and created my own test cases and came up with this:

```
// mock objects
let capital = UILabel()
capital.text = "A"
let nameEnglish = UILabel()
nameEnglish.text = "B"
let nameLocal = UILabel()
nameLocal.text = "C"
let currencyCode = UILabel()
currencyCode.text = "D"

var searchText = "\(capital.text) \(nameEnglish.text) \(nameLocal.text) \(currencyCode.text)".lowercaseString
print(searchText)
```

which results to:

> "optional("a") optional("b") optional("c") optional("d")"

Obviously, adding if-let results in:

```
if let cap = capital.text, neng = nameEnglish.text, nloc = nameLocal.text, curr = currencyCode.text {
    searchText = "\(cap) \(neng) \(nloc) \(curr)".lowercaseString
    print(searchText)
}
```

> "a b c d"

The compiler told you it was too complex to connect Strings the way you did. Connect them like this or incrementally and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Casting each variable as a String helped in my case.

```
var searchText = (String(capital.text) + " " + String(nameEnglish.text) + " " + String(nameLocal.text) + " " + String(currencyCode.text)).lowercaseString
```